# Greasemonkey change div id class

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I'm trying to change the class to "sidebar" and style height to "50%" of this div (Facebook):

```
<div id="pagelet_ticker" class="hidden_elem" style="height: 0px;">
```

I don't know why the following Greasemonkey script is not working. Any suggestions are much appreciated. Thank you!
---Edited to reflect the changes suggested --- still not working

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Ticker
// @namespace      Ticker
// @description    Ticker
// @include        https://www.facebook.com
// ==/UserScript==

var query = document.querySelector('#pagelet_ticker'); //added #
        query.setAttribute("class", "sidebar");
        query.setAttribute("style", "height: 50%;");  //changed attribute to style
```

Comment: Your querySelector is missing the # for the id lookup.

Comment: I'm pretty sure HTML elements don't have a `height` attribute.

Comment: Does not work with '#pagelet_ticker' either :(

Comment: @melpomene, I'm trying to make the facebook news ticker visible, this is how I see it in Firebug:

[link]https://imgur.com/a/qCdXC

Comment: Yes, that's a `style` attribute.

Comment: @melpomene, of course you're right, thank you!

Still doesn't work, though...

Answer (score 2):

I did it using this:

`var ticker = document.getElementById ("pagelet_ticker");
ticker.classList.remove ("hidden_elem");
ticker.classList.add ("sidebar");
ticker.style.height = '200px';`

Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```js
var query = document.querySelector('#pagelet_ticker'); //added #
query.classList.add('sidebar');
query.style.height = "50%";  //changed attribute to style
```

```css
.sidebar {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="pagelet_ticker" class="hidden_elem" style="height: 0px;">Wee</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, no :(